# Right way to create a custom control library in winui

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, winui-3, winui

i want to create a custom control library with winui 3/uwp.

The question is **How should I introduce dictionaries and styles?**

Why did PowerToys put some dictionaries in the [generic file](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys/blob/master/src/settings-ui/Microsoft.PowerToys.Settings.UI/Themes/Generic.xaml)? And put some other dictionaries in the [app.xaml](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys/blob/master/src/settings-ui/Microsoft.PowerToys.Settings.UI/App.xaml) file?

I also noticed that one of the dictionaries (IsEnabledTextBlock) was placed in both the **generic** file and the **app.xaml** file. why?

If we want to create a custom control library, how should we introduce these dictionaries and styles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are developing a library that contains custom controls, the default styles of these controls should be defined in a resource dictionary called `themes/generic.xaml`. This is where the framework will look for them by convention.

A class library has no concept of an app global `App.xaml` file since it's not an app.

Comment: i know that app.xaml is not exist in class library but why pt defined some resource in generic and some in app.xaml?

Comment: You should ask the author(s) about that but probably because both the controls and the app have default styling. I don't really see what this has to do with your custom class library though. Obviously you don't have any `App.xaml` anyway.